# Javascript / Jquery onclick function condensation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if what can I do with my codes to make it shorter.
Here is my code, it is like a simple tabs.
Btw, this codes are already working, but I'm thinking that if i have many tabs then I have to repeat many click functions.
Is there a way to make my script shorter, Thanks in advance.

```
$(function () {
    $(".invMer, .invEq").hide();

    $(".mergers a").click(function () {
        $(".invMer").fadeIn();
        $(".invEq, .invPe").hide();
    });

    $(".equity a").click(function () {
        $(".invEq").fadeIn();
        $(".invMer, .invPe").hide();
    });

    $(".privateEq a").click(function () {
        $(".invPe").fadeIn();
        $(".invMer, .invEq").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Not trying to pick on you @camdev, your question and code implementation is a great example of the less experienced a developer is, the more complex their code is,just something to always keep in mind,if things are getting crazy,duplicated,hard to read,hard to maintain, the code is just too complex for no reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give all the links the same class, and a data attribute that says which tab it should open. So something like:

```
<div class="mergers">
    <a class="tablink" href="#" data-tab="invMer">Mergers</a>
</div>
```

And all the tab DIVs should also have a common class:

```
<div class="tabdiv" id="invMer">
    ...
</div>
```

Then you can use a single handler:

```
$(".tablink").click(function() {
    var tab = '#' + $(this).data("tab");
    $(".tabdiv").not(tab).hide();
    $(tab).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a data attribute

```
<a data-show=".invPe">
```

and do

```
$("a[data-show]").on("click", function () {
    var selector = $(this).data("show"); 
    $(".invMer, .invEq, .invPe").hide();
    $(selector).fadeIn();
});
```